# How can I change the size and color of anchors in ARCORE?

Tags: android, mobile, arcore

I'm just new to using ArCore API and I can't seem to find how to change the color and the size of anchors in my android app. I'm building a measuring app using ArCore and the size of the anchors and their color is really out of the theme that I'm trying to make.
[This is the current status of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl2ok.png)

Any help would do, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

State the color as a float variable like this:

```
private static final float[] MODEL_COLOR = new float[] {250.0f, 250.0f, 250.0f, 255.0f};
```

Then, use this variable to set the color of the model in the draw method:

```
objectModel.draw(cameraView, cameraPerspective, colorCorrectionRGBA, MODEL_COLOR)
```

I imagine you can do the same with the size, though I'm not sure.